# ASP.NET :What advantage if i use using when creating an object

Tags: asp.net

in ASP.NET, I have seen people coding like this

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{

   // Do the datatbase transactions

}
```

How does it differ from this one

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString)
 // Do the datatbase transactions
```

Is there any performance/speed improvements in using one over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a shortcut. :)

```
using (var foo = new Foo())
    foo.bar();
```

equals to:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 try
  {
      foo.bar();
  }
  finally
  {
    if (foo != null)
      ((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
  }
```

using keyword ensures that object will be disposed (it must implement IDisposable).
It's useful when working with external resources (database connection, file streams etc.) - they will be released despite of errors that may occur.

Answer (score 3):

> The using statement allows the
>   programmer to specify when objects
>   that use resources should release
>   them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the
>   IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which
>   should release the object's resources.
>
> A using statement can be exited either
>   when the end of the using statement is
>   reached or if an exception is thrown
>   and control leaves the statement block
>   before the end of the statement.

A good article can be found here

[Understanding the 'using' statement in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tinguusingstatement.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using: Defines a scope, outside of which an object or objects will be disposed.

So its just syntax instead of creating the object then disposing it.

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) syntax for any object that implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) - for example, `SqlConnection`.

The `using` statement ensures that the object is disposed correctly at the end of the block in (almost) all circumstances, even if exceptions occur.

There aren't any direct speed/performance differences either way, but if you don't dispose of your `IDisposable` objects (usually by using `using`) then you might encounter problems down the line because vital resources haven't been tidied up.

Using `using` is good practice and almost always the right way to do things. *Not* using `using` is usually a bad idea, unless you're absolutely certain of what you're doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

objects created in the using construct have lifetime within the construct (the braces {}). And if you notice only those members which implement the IDisposable interface can only be created. It simply means that right after the using construct code the the compiler will automatically call the dispose method on the object you've created. It helps in garbage collection.

As in the case of SqlConnection objects we must call dispose otherwise the ado.net connection pool (which manages connections to database) will assign a new connection to another incoming request instead of reusing an old connection pool. Connection pooling is simply an inherent way to minimize the resources & time taken to acquire a connection to a database.

Refer:
Connection Pooling
IDisposable

Answer (score 0):

using statement is a shortcut for

```
try
{
    /* do the work here with obj */

}
finally
{
    if (obj != null)
        obj.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the using statement would automatically call the finally, i.e once the using block is finished, it will dispose off the object.

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
   // Do the datatbase transactions
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString)
// Do the datatbase transactions
    myConnection.Close();
    myConnection.Dispose()
```

Comment: with a try/finally thrown in as well, to make sure that whatever happens, the Close and Dispose are called.